# " inside attribute in xslt

Tags: asp.net, regex, xslt

hi i am trying to write a regular expression inside an xslt 
but i have a problem with the " sign.
i closes the attribute. and \" dosnt seem to work like it works in aspx pages

here is my code:

```
<xsl:if test="@text = 'yes'">
  <asp:RegularExpressionValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="{@name}" 
   ValidationExpression="^[\w '%+*.!=/\\\[\]\{\}\?\,\(\)-]+$"
   ErrorMessage=" " Display="Dynamic">
      <span class="red_star">*</span>
  </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
</xsl:if>
```

how can i add the " sign to the regular expression?
so it will be like this:

ValidationExpression="^[\w '%+*.!=/\[]{}\?\,()\"-]+$"

thank you

Comment: &quot; should do the work, but I don't know much xslt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape the `"` character to `&quot;`:

```
<xsl:if test="@text = 'yes'">
  <asp:RegularExpressionValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="{@name}" 
   ValidationExpression="^[\w '%+*.!=/\\\[\]\{\}\?\,\(\)\&quot;-]+$"
   ErrorMessage=" " Display="Dynamic">
      <span class="red_star">*</span>
  </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
</xsl:if>
```

There are 5 character that if you need to output in XML need to be escaped:

```
 - " (&quot;)
 - ' (&apos;)
 - < (&lt;)
 - > (&gt;)
 - & (&amp;)
```

Comment: Escaping `>` is usually not required (only matters sometimes within a CDATA). Also, one of `"` or `'` can be left unescaped if the other character isn't present in the string (the other character can be used as the string delimiter).

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to express " with the xml entity &quot;

Answer (score 0):

Since you're generating another XML document (or aspx, or HTML, for that matter), I believe you need a little more encoding. For the example, suppose you want `attribute` to be `abc"edf`:

`attr="abc&quot;edf"`, as suggested, will cause the XSL engine to see the text as `attr="abc"edf"`. In this case, the XSL is valid, but *the generated document isn't!*.

What you probably need here is:

```
attr="abc&amp;quot;edf"
```

Here, the XSL engine sees and generates `attr="abc&quot;edf"` - that is, you want `&quot;` to be **part of the output**, not the input.

[alt text http://yuml.me/3b1e45](http://yuml.me/3b1e45)

<sub>(As an alernative, you might get away with single quotes: `attr='abc&quot;edf'` - this wouldn't help here though, because you also have a single quote in your string...)</sub>

Comment: Your answer is misleading and untrue. This is not how the XSL engine works. The XSL engine is, as expected, XML-aware. This means that when it generates the document, it first generates an XML tree which is THEN serialized into an XML string if needed (often it isn't)

So, first, the XML and XSL documents are parsed into XML objects. At this point, the literal value of attribute "attr" is parsed and stored as: abc"edf. Then that attribute value is set to the result document attribute again literally, i.e. resulting abc&quot;edf when serialized. Try it in any XSL engine and see for yourself :-)

Comment: @dionyziz - you are right, and the two answers above make that point. However, I'm pretty sure there where cases I had to use `&amp;quot;` or `&amp;amp;` - I'll check on Sunday and update the answer to explain when this is appropriate (disable output escaping?). If I'm totally wrong, I'll delete it. Don't worry `:)`